# Django many to many relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I have a user model and a group model.

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

 class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

 class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    group = models.ManyToManyField('Group')
```

I have a scenario in which a user can be an admin or just a member of a group. A group can have many admins as well as it can have many members.
How can I define such a relation in Django and query things like **"Admins of a group", "members of group", "groups where a user is an admin", "groups where a user is a member"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **ManyToMany** intermediary model using **'through'** argument.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='GroupMembership', related_name='groups')

class GroupMembership(models.Model):
    ROLE_CHOICE = (
        ('1', 'Admin'),
        ('2', 'Member'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(choices=ROLE_CHOICE, default='2', max_length=1)
```

all the members in a 'group'

```
group.members.all()
```

all the admins of the 'group'

```
group.members.filter(groupmembership__role=1)
```

All groups where 'john' is admin

```
Group.objects.filter(members__name='john', groupmembership__role=1)
```

Groups where 'user' is admin

```
user.groups.filter(groupmembership__role=1)
```

Comment: **How to create a membership object.?** I'm trying to create a membership object in model form's save method of a model say 'account'.