# Django model - Foreign Key / Float pair

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is there any way to have a foreign key/float pair in a model? I have an `Item` model and an `Enemy` model currently, and would like to add a field to the `Enemy` that is essentially a chance of getting an item from defeating it.

I would like to be able to define, for example, a 10% chance to get `Item` A and a 1% chance to get `Item` B when you defeat an `Enemy`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772288/django-many-to-many-relationship

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772288/django-many-to-many-relationship)